# langchain.memory is not recognised in my import statement

Tags: langchain

I'm trying to import ConversationMemoryBuffer using this line from the docs, `from langchain.memory import ConversationBufferMemory`

`langchain.memory` has an error line and doesn't work. statements such as these:

```
from langchain.prompts import PromptTemplate
from langchain.chains import LLMChain, SequentialChain
```

are used and work just fine. I've installed everything and even uninstalled/reinstalled it. What could be the issue?

I tried the line `from langchain.memory import ConversationBufferMemory` and was expecting it to work without errors so I could proceed to add buffermemory to my app.

Comment: import works okay for me, pls put the full error trace log, so can understand more about the error.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```py
from langchain.chains.conversation.memory import ConversationBufferMemory
```

Might work for your case.